# Windows 10 Pro Laptop: Logon displayed after I close lid

Tags: windows-10, laptop

Running Windows 10 Pro (OS build: 19045.3448) on a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop.  When I close the lid, the power options are to "do nothing" regardless if it is powered or on battery.  Later, when I open the lid, I'm greeted with a logon screen.  How do I disable/eliminate this behavior. Thanks RDK

Comment: Is it a logon screen or the screensaver that asks for password? Do you have a screensaver?

Comment: It appears to be a logon screen which wants Id and pw to continue.  I have face recognition activated and it eventually gets a positive match...

Comment: Do you have a screensaver?

Comment: no screen saver

Comment: Have you checked settings in *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*, and especially the "Sleep" branch?